# Datefield in LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I would like to know if there is any `datefield/datepicker` component for `LWUIT` ?

Or, will there be any work around for implement `datefield in lwuit`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other possible solution is use a LWUIT Calendar.
http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/iodocs/index.html

I think it's the best solution for dates in LWUIT.

Comment: Which LWUIT version includes this component ?

Comment: I know version 1.5 has a calendar. Just be sure to import the lwuit calendar library and not the java micro edition one.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Form form = new Form("Spinners");
Spinner integerSpinner = Spinner.create(0, 1000, 100, 10);
Spinner decimalSpinner = Spinner.create(0.0, 100.0, 17.75, 0.05);
Spinner timeSpinner = Spinner.createTime(0, 24 * 60 * 60, 10 * 60 * 60, 60, true, false);
Spinner dateSpinner = Spinner.createDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000 * DAY,
System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * DAY, System.currentTimeMillis(),
'-', Spinner.DATE_FORMAT_MM_DD_YYYY);

form.setLayout(new TableLayout(4, 2));
form.addComponent(new Label("Integer"));
form.addComponent(integerSpinner);
form.addComponent(new Label("Decimal"));
form.addComponent(decimalSpinner);
form.addComponent(new Label("Time"));
form.addComponent(timeSpinner);
form.addComponent(new Label("Date"));
form.addComponent(dateSpinner);
form.show();
```

Comment: DAY is the value of miliseconds from 1970 jan 1 without the last 000 numbers.

Comment: How can i assign this value to DAY?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `DateField` or `DatePicker` components in LWUIT. So you can use [`Spinner`](http://www.lwuit.com/2009/12/spinning-it-round-and-round.html) instead of `DateField`.

And I found one [third party application](http://sites.google.com/site/franciscobenitezleon/projects/lwuit-datefield) for use `DateField` in LWUIT. They have used LWUIT and developed `DateField` component. But I'm not sure how it works. Let me the status if you use.

Comment: Hi bharath, Thanks for replying. I would like to use the spinner mentioned in your reply but i could not figure out the DAY in that code...can i get some leads on that?

Comment: Use `private static final long DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Spinner` class. It has no constructor but it has static methods for creating a Spinner.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `Calendar` class.

Answer (score 0):

There is some like Mobrizdatefiled in lwuit , its just using lcdui datepicker and using its functional implementation in lwuit.

[LWUIT DATEFIELD](http://bluetrail.co.uk/2009/06/lwuit-datefield-and-other-bits/)